# Why lombok throws this strange error with NeoVim jdtls setup?

Tags: java, spring, lombok, neovim

I am trying to setup NeoVim with java. I follow this [setup](https://github.com/mfussenegger/nvim-jdtls/wiki/Sample-Configurations).

The setup includes, obviously, lombok and it is a Spring application. When I check what is in the `lsp.log` file I see the error below which happens when NeoVim communicates to the `eclipse.jdt.ls` server.

I just don't understand why this error happens. The project can be compiled by maven from both command line and IntelliJ.

What I checked so far:

- I have the same lombok version in my project (provided by Spring) and on my file system (the nvim-jdtls configuration says it must be specified)
- I searched for the error message, but nothing related
- `jdtls` is installed by `brew` on my Mac
- the configuration seems ok as the java processes shows that lombok is included (`ps aux | grep java` output is down there

```
[ERROR][2024-01-26 19:44:18] ...lsp/handlers.lua:535    
26 Jan 2024, 19:44:18 
Lombok annotation handler class lombok.eclipse.handlers.HandleGetter failed
'java.lang.StringBuffer org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Expression.print(int, java.lang.StringBuffer)'
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.StringBuffer org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Expression.print(int, java.lang.StringBuffer)'
at lombok.eclipse.handlers.EclipseHandlerUtil.createAnnotation(EclipseHandlerUtil.java:1335)
at lombok.eclipse.HandlerLibrary$AnnotationHandlerContainer.handle(HandlerLibrary.java:105)
at lombok.eclipse.HandlerLibrary.handleAnnotation(HandlerLibrary.java:237)
at lombok.eclipse.TransformEclipseAST$AnnotationVisitor.visitAnnotationOnField(TransformEclipseAST.java:245)
at lombok.eclipse.EclipseNode.traverse(EclipseNode.java:110)
at lombok.eclipse.EclipseAST.traverseChildren(EclipseAST.java:231)
at lombok.eclipse.EclipseNode.traverse(EclipseNode.java:79)
at lombok.eclipse.EclipseAST.traverseChildren(EclipseAST.java:231)
at lombok.eclipse.EclipseNode.traverse(EclipseNode.java:74)
at lombok.eclipse.EclipseAST.traverseChildren(EclipseAST.java:231)
at lombok.eclipse.EclipseNode.traverse(EclipseNode.java:69)
at lombok.eclipse.EclipseAST.traverse(EclipseAST.java:224)
at lombok.eclipse.TransformEclipseAST.go(TransformEclipseAST.java:222)
at lombok.eclipse.TransformEclipseAST.transform(TransformEclipseAST.java:183)
at lombok.eclipse.TransformEclipseAST.transform_swapped(TransformEclipseAST.java:107)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
at lombok.launch.PatchFixesHider$Util.invokeMethod(PatchFixesHider.java:133)
at lombok.launch.PatchFixesHider$Transform.transform_swapped(PatchFixesHider.java:256)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.endParse(Parser.java:12067)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:13269)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:13499)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:13456)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.dietParse(Parser.java:11838)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.internalBeginToCompile(Compiler.java:850)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.beginToCompile(Compiler.java:393)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:447)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:425)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:411)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.compile(BatchImageBuilder.java:214)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:342)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.build(BatchImageBuilder.java:79)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildAll(JavaBuilder.java:286)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:192)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:1077)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:296)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:352)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:441)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:47)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:444)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:555)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:503)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:585)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:207)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:300)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

ps aux

```
andrascsanyi     30619   0.0  4.3 414060112 1439760   ??  Ss    8:20PM   0:26.60 java -javaagent:/Users/andrascsanyi/.local/share/java/lombok-1.18.30.jar -Declipse.application=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.id1 -Dosgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4 -Declipse.product=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.product -Dlog.protocol=true -Dlog.level=ALL -Xmx2G -Xms1G --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -jar /opt/homebrew/Cellar/jdtls/1.31.0/libexec/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.700.v20231214-2017.jar -configuration /opt/homebrew/Cellar/jdtls/1.31.0/libexec/config_mac -data /Users/andrascsanyi/.workspace/interviews

andrascsanyi     30652   0.0  0.6 419974960 191456   ??  S     8:20PM   0:03.48 /Users/andrascsanyi/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/java-language-server/dist/mac/bin/java --add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED -classpath /Users/andrascsanyi/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/java-language-server/dist/classpath/gson-2.8.5.jar:/Users/andrascsanyi/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/java-language-server/dist/classpath/protobuf-java-3.19.3.jar:/Users/andrascsanyi/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/java-language-server/dist/classpath/java-language-server.jar org.javacs.Main
```

Comment: It is a bug in lombok: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/3564

Answer (score 0):

As already noted by the question author, this is an issue on lombok's side. Note that this is not a problem with detecting lombok on the classpath (also sometimes an issue with `jdtls`). The current fix at the time of writing (03.24) is to use the edge release of lombok (version `1.18.31`) available [here](https://projectlombok.org/download-edge). You might need to run `:JdtWipeDataAndRestart` in neovim for your project afterward to get a clean recompilation. As soon as it becomes the stable version, this should resolve itself by updating in the usual manner.