# Builder annotation access level private

Tags: java, lombok

I'm getting this compilation error:

> Lombok annotation handler class lombok.eclipse.handlers.HandleBuilder failed - See error log. Java (0) [1, 1]

> The method builder() is undefined for the type NestedReference Java (67108964) [22, 26]

My class is:

```java
package net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.domain.model.reference;

import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@Builder(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class NestedReference {
    private final ReferenceId referenceId;

    private NestedReference(ReferenceId referenceId) {
        validate(referenceId);
        this.referenceId = referenceId;
    }

    public static NestedReference of(ReferenceId referenceId) {
        return NestedReference.builder()   // <<<< The method builder() is undefined for the type NestedReference Java (67108964) [22, 26]
                .referenceId(referenceId)
                .build();
    }

    private static void validate(ReferenceId referenceId) {
        if (referenceId == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ReferenceId cannot be null or empty");
        }
    }
}
```

My class is a immutable Value Object and I need to leverage `@Builder` annotation `builder` only inside my class.

Any ideas?

Comment: May be related https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=583026

Comment: Are you on the very newest eclipse? As of writing, broken, but patch is already contributed, we're about to review it.

Comment: I'm using last jdtls version `v.1.33.0`

Answer (score 0):

Calling `NestedReference.builder()` should work.

Which version of Java and Lombok are you using?

Have you tried calling the `NestedReferenceBuilder` constructor directly?

```java
public static NestedReference of(ReferenceId referenceId) {
    return new NestedReferenceBuilder()
            .referenceId(referenceId)
            .build();
}
```

#### Alternative to builder

You can leverage the power of records and Lombok in a different way:

```java
import lombok.NonNull;

public record NestedReference(@NonNull ReferenceId referenceId) {}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NestedReference ref = new NestedReference(null);
    System.out.println(ref);
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: referenceId is marked non-null but is null
    at org.example.NestedReference.<init>(NestedReference.java:5)
    at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

If you cannot use records yet, you can use `@Value`:

```
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.Value;

@Value
public class NestedReference {
    @NonNull ReferenceId referenceId;
}
```

Comment: It keeps failing: `NestedReferenceBuilder cannot be resolved to a type Java`. I'm using `1.18.30` and java 17.

Comment: It's strange, I'm using neovim, and I'm getting this compilation errors. When I'm using `mvn` straightforadly, it works... Any ideas?

Comment: @Jordi Could this be related?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78146944/1762224